# How to configure selenium for CEF/Winforms applications (exe)

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cefsharp

Main Question: How does one configure selenium for CEFsharp applications in C#?

If anyone is having issues with configuring selenium to CEFsharp applications please take a look at this post. I had a tough time and scoured the internet to make this happen and I want to share this information with others.

My Environment:

- VS 2017
- C# backend/middleware
- Angular frontend
- CEF to encapsulate application
- Application is exe

Comment: Where is the information exactly?

Comment: @DebanjanB sorry for the late reply, but you probably have already seen it posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Make sure your application uses RemoteDebugging (in main program file):

```
 static void Main()
        {
            var cefSettings = new CefSettings
            {
                WindowlessRenderingEnabled = true,
                MultiThreadedMessageLoop = true,
                BrowserSubprocessPath = @"CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe",  
                LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Error,
            };
            cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("--disable-pinch", "1");

#if DEBUG
            **cefSettings.RemoteDebuggingPort = port#;**
#endif
        Cef.Initialize(cefSettings);
```

If using angular make sure to include (in clientshellwinforms section):

```
#if DEBUG

           _webView.Load("http://localhost:portForAngular");
#endif
```

To connect to application on selenium use:

```
 public void Main()
    {
        var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("remote-debugging-port=port#");
        chromeOptions.DebuggerAddress = "localhost:port#";
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);
    }
```

Then you should be able to drive through using selenium.

Things to consider:

As long as the application has remote debugging enabled you can open it and then run the selenium functions.

Use chrome://inspect (instead or debugger port) to take full advantage of dev tools.

Nuget:

1. Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver 2.34.0 (Old, but gold)
2. Selenium.Support & Selenium.WebDriver 3.141.0
3. NUnit/NUnit3TestAdapter 3.11/3.13
4. DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects 3.11.0

Good luck!